# execute and download jasperserver report through url

Tags: url, download, report, execute, jasperserver

Is there any way to execute and download the report on jasperserver through single url ? I am able to login and open the report url and pass the parameters, all is set but i need to execute it and download it in excel format.

http://jasperserver_url.com/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&j_username=username&j_password=password&ParentFolderUri=%2FReports&reportUnit=%2FReports%2FMy_Report&parameter1=param1&decorate=no

Do I need to pass some more parameters ?
Or some other way is there ?

Answer (score 1):

Append **"&output=excel"** in your report URL for downloading it in Excel format.

For Example:

Use this URL:

```html
http://jasperserver_url.com/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&j_username=username&j_password=password&ParentFolderUri=%2FReports&reportUnit=%2FReports%2FMy_Report&parameter1=param1&decorate=no&output=excel
```